# Link to post's ID (Wp)

Tags: wordpress, post, categories, slug, permalinks

I am having trouble linking to a single post. I have queried my loop to show posts categories that match the slug. So I only need one gallery template.

This has made an issue for me that means i cant simply use `get_permalink()`.

My codes is below but does not work. Any thoughts?

```
<div id="tile-container">
<?php query_posts(array('category_name' => $post->post_name));?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php

    $link = the_permalink( $post->ID );

    echo '<div class="tile-posts">';
    echo '<a href="' . echo $link . '">';
      the_content();
    echo '</a>"';
    echo '</div>';

  ?>


  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `the_permalink()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

or you can also reference the post url by using `$post->post_name`

also i noticed this:

```
echo '<a href="' . echo get_permalink($link) . '">';
```

since you already assignd `$link` to the `get_permalink()` method above you don't need to pass `$link` in as a parameter to `get_permalink()` - you should just be able to echo it as so

```
echo '<a href="' . $link . '">';
```

Comment: yea - i've seen all the code - check out my answer it should help

Comment: I have tried but it displays blank page on my gallery. The plan is to link to the post displaying single.php

Comment: is the link outputting in the html? is it just the link anchor text that is blank?

Comment: if I use just the_permalink() it goes to the image url. Using the code above you kindly suggested the gallery page is in fact blank. white page

Comment: <?php query_posts(array('category_name' => $post->post_name));?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php

    $link = the_permalink( $post->ID );

    echo '<div class="tile-posts">';
    echo '<a href="' . echo $link . '">';
      the_content();
    echo '</a>"';
    echo '</div>';

  ?>


  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

Comment: ok check revision, i removed echo from echo $link - that should haven't been there - my bad

Comment: Ermm were is the revision sorry

Comment: should be in the answer above, you may need to refresh, echo '<a href="' . $link . "'>

Comment: This displays the permalink still e.g. /street. I am trying to get to the single post. Since all my posts in this category have the permalink .../street.